# Openvpn for ubuntu-phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, openvpn, nexus-4

i have ubuntu-phone on nexus 4. Are there plans to make openvpn accessable without the need of switching to read-write mode?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are plans to add support for VPNs. No, support does not exist yet in the UI.